# Mock not-needed React components with Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, integration-testing, enzyme

Let's imagine that we have this **Page** component:

```
const Page = () =>
  <>
    <Topbar />
    <Drawer />
    <Content />
  </>
```

I'd like to test some interaction within the **Drawer** and the **Content** components in an integration test, mounting our **Page** component, so I'd write a mock for the **Topbar** component, because I don't need it, with:

```
jest.mock('./Topbar', () => {
  const TopbarMock = () => null
  return TopbarMock
})
```

Then our tests won't render this component, increasing its execution time and it's less open to fail due to some bug introduced there, isolating our feature.

The problem I have is that, every time I need to add a new component in the **Page** component, I have to do the same I did for the **Topbar**.

My question is if there is any way to specify the components you're going to need for this integration test instead of the ones that you won't need (exactly the other way around). Something like, for this feature that I'm currently testing, I'll just need the **Drawer** and the **Content** components, so don't render anything else.

Or, is there a better way to write integration tests without needing to mock?

Comment: what kind of _interactio_ do you mean? maybe [`shallow()`](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/shallow.html) fulfill your needs without mocking components manually

Comment: Imagine that I want to write an integration test to check that, when you click on a button within the Drawer component, the Content component should send an HTTP request and render a loading spinner. I'll need to use [`mount()`](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/mount.html) in this situation.

Comment: I see. it's about approach to choose. I'd create 3 separate unit tests where do check in isolation: 1) for `Drawer` to check if props callback is called upon clicking child button; 2) for `Content` I'd check if it sends HTTP request once it's prop is changed accordingly; 3) finally I'd check `Page` to change `Content`s props if appropriate `Drawer` prop callback been called; once all 3 suites passed - everything is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such functionality in Enzyme because this is uncommon testing strategy.

A common testing strategy is to have extensive unit test coverage and less restrictive E2E tests. Integration tests can be added to sensitive units that need more attention.

It's impractical to mock all components in the same way. In made-up testing scenario mocking arbitrary components with `() => null` could work, but in real-world scenario this could cause problems in parent component because it could expect children to behave differently than no-op component.

Testing all possible unit interactions in integration tests would result in too many couples. The necessity to do this means that unit tests aren't thorough. Such integration tests result in a lot of extra work with little value because they don't take possible interactions between multiple units into account. Mocked units could make a difference that would make a test to fail.

In this case it's enough to have unit test for `Page` that does shallow render and asserts that it's 'dumb' wrapper for `Topbar`, etc. Children can be tested in their respective unit tests.

Comment: Interesting explanation. Nevertheless, I'm still wondering how can I test a particular interaction between both (or more) components in an integration test without worrying about other components rendered in the same tree. If my app increases considerably in size, rendering everything will make my test suite really slow and this is were I found useful to write different tests structured in different files (like by feature).

Comment: *without worrying about other components rendered in the same tree* - you best leave them as is for integration. In integration tests usually only units that do unwanted actions (performing real HTTP requests) are mocked. As I said, mocking components can result in wrong behaviour, especially when they are stubbed automatically like `() => null`. If Content affects Page or Topbar directly or indirectly, they will behave differently with mocked Content.  *make my test suite really slow* - integration and e2e tests aren't supposed to be fast. They are slow by design and thus run relatively rare.